# Does Poco work with LLVM standard C++ library?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

C++ is not currently one of my main languages - still learning. . . (so go easy on me). .

I'm setting up Poco on iOS. . . It works when I link against Gnu C++ standard library, but when linking against LLVM standard library I get a bunch of errors - unable to find std::string. . .

Does it work with llvm standard lib?

Does it work with C++11 (interesting questin, but not that important since I'm also interested in targeting Android and using Poco for the Threading).

Comment: Try to reduce the problem: Remove Poco and then try to run a simple application using std::string. Concerning support for different C++ flavours (89/11) by LLVM, I'd check the documentation. BTW: C++11 has a std::thread class, which would make that part of Poco unnecessary.

Comment: @doomster Thanks, I'll try that. . . Regarding C++11 threads: still doesn't work Android!

Comment: @doomster Result: a std::string is happy enough with either llvm C++ or GNU C++ lib (compiled with clang in either case), but Poco is only happy with Gnu C++ lib. . . Actually the dialect 98 vs 11 had little bearing on it. . . It was the std lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have built static libraries that work for both iOS, and also for Android: using the Android platform notes presented [here](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/99300-AndroidPlatformNotes.html)

Minor edits to the code should make poco work using stlport_static. but using gnustl_static works out of the box.

the iOS static library work out of the box in Xcode using: c-dialect:GNU99, c++-dialect GNU++11, C++-library libc++ and the LLVM 4.2 compiler.

```
GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu99
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu++0x
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++
```

(One tiny edit might be needed on version 1.51 of poco for [iOS](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/pull/58) and [Android](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/57), if stl-library version you have is different from the std:: namespace used in Poco).

Answer (score 1):

Depends which version you use, 1.5.1 release should work (see https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/46 ). I don't think the fix was backported to 1.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no other answers, answering based on the advice from the comments:

As of Jan, 2013, it will work with C++11 dialect, but it doesn't seem to like the llvm std lib. . Gnu std lib works.